# Regex for matching optional parameters as groups in string

Tags: python, regex, string, optional-parameters

I am trying to read a batch script containing an input string of a command and optional parameters like

```
input = 'command -a field1 -b field2 -c field3'
```

The option parameters are set by a user in a file and I am obtaining the string by reading the file. If the option is included I would need to extract the field.

I currently have my regex as:

```
expr = '^(?P<exec>[^\s]+) -m (?P<mode>[^\s]+) -d (?P<machine>[^\s]+) -p (?P<port>[^\s]+)'
m = re.match(expr, input)
```

When the user includes all the options in the same order, the regex matches the string and the groups are captured. Here is a sample output.

```
{   'exec': 'custom-script',
    'mode': 'debug',
    'machine': 'desk-123',
    'port': '7905'   }
```

However, if any option is not included, or if they are in different orders, the regex fails. How do I modify my regex to perform in these two cases?

Answer (score 5):

In Python you can use the built in optparse or argparse modules to do this for you so you don't have to fidget with hardcore regular expressions which will fail eventually :-)

Comment: Yes! Don't reinvent the wheel!

Comment: Unfortunately, all I have access to is a batch script file containing the input string. I am just reading the line and if match, extracting the values for further processing.

Comment: [shlex.split](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html#shlex.split) can be used to split your source string into an args list, which will definitely be easier to parse on it's own, but you can also pass the result into optparse / argparse in place of the default script args. so you *can* use them for your case.

Answer (score 2):

parsing command line options with regular expressions in python is very fragile - [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) will let you handle all of the arguments you want, both optional and positional, and provides abundant faculties for manipulating them.  It even automatically builds a `-h` option for you!

For example, in your case you said you have the input supplied to you, so you could do the following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('-m','--mode', help='The mode to run in')
parser.add_argument('-d','--machine', help='The machine of interest')
parser.add_argument('-p','--port', help='The port of interest')
args = parser.parse_args(input.split())
```

The output from this, `args`, will have the different fields as attributes, i.e., `args.mode`, `args.machine`, `args.port`

Comment: Just edited my question to clarify. I am not building the command. Rather, I am parsing a batch script which contains the input string, and am trying to extract the information.

Comment: I noticed that in your comment to ikanobori.  `argparse` can still handle that case, so I edited my answer accordingly!

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks. Been wracking my brain over this since a while. It is even human-friendly, so I won;t have too much documentation when I hand over this code :)

Comment: args is of type tuple. But when I try to print args, I get a dictionary. When I try to access args.mode, I get AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'mode'.

Comment: For me, `type(args)` returns `<class 'argparse.Namespace'>` - and when I run `str(args)`, I get the following: `"Namespace(machine='field2', mode='field1', port='field3')"` - what version of python are you running?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I modified it for optparse. Sorry. This machine runs Python 2.4.3

Comment: I fixed it by giving (args, others) = parser.parse_args(input.split())

Comment: Ah!  That makes a lot more sense.  I'm glad you could use my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nate, I used optparse instead of regexes and used the following code:

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_option('-m','--mode', help='The mode to run in')
parser.add_option('-d','--machine', help='The machine of interest')
parser.add_option('-p','--port', help='The port of interest')
(args, others) = parser.parse_args(input.split())
```

Now, I can access the values by args.mode, args.machine, etc.